# Default values for all users in mysql table

Tags: mysql

In my app, I allow people to create additional rooms for inventory purposes. Let's say I have a table called "user_data." The `d_key` field is the data type for a lack of a better description. I have that just in case I introduce more custom fields for the user. Anyways, I want every user to have a room that's called `None`. This way any item that doesn't have a room assigned to it will default to "None."

What's the best way to introduce `None` into the table? Users won't be able to delete this default room, but they can edit/delete rooms they input into the DB table.

`user_data` table

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| d_key   | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| d_value | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sample data:

```
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| id | user_id | d_key    | d_value      |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
| 20 |       2 | location | bedroom      |
| 21 |       2 | location | living room  |
| 22 |       2 | location | attic        |
| 23 |       3 | location | kitchen      |
+----+---------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Would it make sense (easy way out), to insert a new row for them upon account creation? I just have to make sure they can't remove the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the row as part of your user creation process.

For existing users, loop over the users and ensure they have a "none" room; if they don't, insert one.

Comment: Possibly useful idea: add a boolean "deletable" column in case you decide other rooms are also not deletable.  For now, the only room with deletable = false would be the "none" room.